# Restrict non whitelisted IP's from viewing Directory list in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I am trying to restrict access to viewing Directory Indexes or viewing lists of files in a directory unless your IP is in a whitelist.

I am using Apache web server and an `.htaccess` file.

So here is what I have so far

```
Options -Indexes
<Files *>
deny from all
allow from 71.56.134.456
allow from 71.55.104.468
Options +Indexes
</Files>
```

This partially works.  This does restrict directory viewing to everyone unless there IP is listed.  The problem is it also restricts non-whitelisted IP's from viewing files as well.

I need to restrict there access from directory lists but not direct file access.

Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "if" directive in apache for flexible configuration and check variable values:

```
options -Indexes
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} == '127.0.0.1'">
    options +Indexes
</If>
```

Comment: Awesome I have looked everywhere for this